# Eliminar elementos relacionados Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo dos tablas una productos y la otra tipo al darle en eliminar un tipo en mi crud es que se elimine sin importar que tenga un producto relacionado
ProductoController

```
    Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('descripcion',5000);
            $table->string('foto');
            $table->bigInteger('id_categoria')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('id_tipo');
            $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            $table->foreign('id_tipo')->references('id')->on('tipo');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

TipoController

```
       Schema::create('tipo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

Modelo tipo

```
    class Tipo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function create(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Producto');
    }
    protected $table = 'tipo';

}
```

Producto Modelo

```
    class Producto extends Model
{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\categoria');
    }
    public function tipo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\tipo');
    }
    //completa las conversaciones WHould o Whouldn´t
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','descripcion','foto','id_categoria','id_tipo'];
}
```

Error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tienda_web`.`productos`, CONSTRAINT `productos_id_tipo_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo`) REFERENCES `tipo` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `tipo` where `id` = 6)
```

Muchas gracias porfavor les pido su ayuda

Comment: ¿Y la duda cuál es?

Comment: que como puedo hacer eso ya que no me sale me sale este error

Comment: Edita por favor tu pregunta, dale un poco mas de contexto a la problemática que enfrentas y agrega que error obtienes

Comment: si claro perdon ya la edite

Comment: debes agregar el delete on cascade, busca acerca de eso

Comment: Aqui tienes la respuesta a tu pregunta: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints (*pista lee donde dice  *onDelete()**)